# Clear android stack and always start app on certain activity

Tags: android, passwords, android-activity, stack

I have an app that it password protected to stop unauthorised access to data.

What I need to ask is:

when app is closed using the home button, then reopened I need it to go to the LoginActivity, I think I have sorted this using android:launchMode="singleTask"

But if I press the back button it takes me back to the menu without the need for logging in again - so it bypasses the password?

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

On your activity, before it goes to background by pressing home, set a flag that the user has logged out or clear the session.

Then onResume of your activity, detect if the flag for user is still logged in or session is still valid.  If not valid. then just send an intent to open your login activity.

So even you press back, that activity that resumed will validate if the user is still logged in or the session is still valid.

Comment: thanks for that.  can you help with an example of the code that may be required please?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom application class with a flag indicating whether the user is logged in.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    boolean loggedIn;
}
```

In your activity you can then check if the user is logged in. If they aren't, return them to the login activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     MyApplication app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
     if (!app.loggedIn) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
         //go to old activity
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```